# Bordism and regular values of a distance map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose $W$ is a compact bordism between two closed manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$, so that $\partial W=M_1\sqcup M_2$. Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $W$, and let $d$ denote the corresponding Riemmanian distance function. Suppose that
$$d(M_1,M_2)=1,$$
where the distance $d(S_1,S_2)$ between two closed subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $W$ is defined to be the infimum of lengths of curves joining a point in $S_1$ to a point in $S_2$.

Consider the function
$$d_{M_1}:W\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$x\mapsto d(x,M_1).$$
I would like to know whether a typical value in $[0,1]$ is a regular value of the function $d_{M_1}$. To be more precise:

**Question 1:** Does the interval $(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)$ contain a regular value of $d_{M_1}$ for every $\epsilon>0$?

**Question 2:** Suppose $a\in[0,1]$ is a regular value of $d_{M_1}$. Then is the submanifold $d_{M_1}^{-1}\{a\}$ bordant to $M_1$?